# How does Xdebug know about breakpoints in an IDE?

Tags: php, ide, xdebug

I am a big proponent of Xdebug and love PhpStorm. I have worked with many different setups for local environments and configuration seems to be a bit different each time.

My current environment is a docker container running on my local machine. I understand that PhpStorm is listening to `0.0.0.0`, aka - to all network interfaces, and on a specified port (I'm using `9004`). I also see that I can ping my local machine from the docker container hosting Xdebug.

What I don't understand is: when I put a breakpoint in PhpStorm, how does Xdebug know that it exists, so that when it hits that line of execution it should tell PhpStorm to stop?

Comment: XDebug is running in PhpStorm's webserver.

Comment: @Barmar What do you mean? The code is being processed in my docker container, which is not in PHPStorm's web server.

Comment: Good point. I'm not sure how it works in that case.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

When Xdebug first connects to the IDE, the IDE sends over a list of breakpoints that it wants Xdebug to interrupt PHP at. If you have a look at a log file (made with `xdebug.log=/tmp/xdebug.log`), then you will see commands being send starting with `breakpoint_set`. There is then a type (`-t`), often `line` for a file/line breakpoint, as well as the file name and line number.

When PHP runs code, Xdebug intercepts the execution, and when it sees a match filename/line number combination, it pauses the execution and goes into command mode so that the IDE can send commands to inspect the current scope (by sending `content_get`) as well as further information about variables (with `property_get`). Then when you click "Continue" or "Step Over", the IDE sends a command to Xdebug to do the equivalent action.

To see a full description of the protocol, give the [DBGp protocol specification](https://xdebug.org/docs/dbgp) a read.

Comment: Great and simple explanation! Thanks!

Comment: I wrote this blog based on your suggestions, would love to hear your comments :) https://medium.com/@jdesrig/xdebug-a-deeper-look-9cea47707c06